# Menu system exit not working as desired

Tags: prolog

I am having trouble with this code below. There is something wrong when I try to exit the menu.

```
   park(_,blue,basketball_court).
time(officehour,_) :- 
    menu2.

go :- start_message,menu1.
start_message :- 
    write('This is a program'),nl.

menu1 :-
    nl,write('Select operation:'),nl,
    write('1. Input time'),nl,
    write('2. Exit program'),nl,
    read(Y), choice1(Y).

choice1(1):-
    write('Place available to be parked:'),nl,
    write('Input time:'),nl,
    read(Y),
    repeat,
    time(Y,X),
    write(X),nl,
    fail,
    menu1.

choice1(2):-
    write('Exit program').


menu2 :- 
    nl,write('Select operation:'),nl,
    write('1. Check which parking area available to park right now.'),nl,
    write('2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.'),nl,
    write('3. End program.'),nl,
    read(X),nl,choice(X).

choice(2):-
    write('Enter your identity:'),nl,
    read(C),
    write('Enter sticker type:'),nl,
    read(D),
    write('Enter parking area:'),nl,
    read(E),
    park(C,D,E),
    menu2.

choice(3):- 
    write('Exit program.').
```

Below is the result when above code run... As you can see, what I want to see is `Exit program. True` and not as below.

```
This is a program
Input time:
officehour
Place available to be parked:

Select operation:
1. Check which parking area available to park right now.
2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.
3. End program.
3

Exit program._896

Select operation:
1. Check which parking area available to park right now.
2. Check whether a particular parking area is legal to park.
3. End program.
```

Just ignore from here. I am just typing to fulfil the requirement to post.....

Comment: `write(X),nl,
    fail,
    menu1.` In this context, `menu1` will *never* execute since `fail` always fails.

Comment: When you call `time(Y, X), write(X), ...` it finds your predicate `time(officehour, _) :-....` The variable `X` is unified with the anonymous variable, `_`. It gets written to the output as `_896`.

Comment: You can use `abort` to stop the program: `choice(3):- 
    write('Exit program.'), abort.` There may be some better way, depending on which Prolog you use, perhaps.

Comment: And you shouldn't have multiple exits like that anyway. You could have a repeat loop in `menu1/0` that ends with a test, not `fail/0`, and if the test succeeds it just stops.

Comment: So the test succeeds if the user selects exit.

Comment: By the way, SWI comes with a nice library routine for making these kinds of things: [menu/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=tty%3Amenu/3).

Comment: I see...
The menu above, the codes I got it from my lecturer but it seems that `menu/3` is a better one...
Thanks!

Comment: I notice there is one more problem.
For code below:
`choice(2):-
    write('Enter your identity:'),nl,
    read(C),
    write('Enter sticker type:'),nl,
    read(D),
    write('Enter parking area:'),nl,
    read(E),
    park(C,D,E),
    menu2.`

I want to verify whether `park(C,D,E)` is true or false and display it before return to `menu2/0`. Any idea how?